# WooCommerce: Manage stock at two different levels

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock

I have the following product attributes, and want to limit stock as shown in the brackets)

```
Destination: Destination_1, Destination_2 (1000 orders available for each destination)

Outgoing Pick up location: Location_1, Location_2 
Outgoing Pick up time: Time_1, Time_2, Time_3, Time_4 (400 orders available for each timeslot - location combination)

Outgoing Drop off location: Location_1, Location_2 
Outgoing Drop off time: Time_1, Time_2, Time_3, Time_4 (400 orders available for each timeslot - location combination)

Incoming Pick up location: Location_1, Location_2 
Incoming Pick up time: Time_1, Time_2, Time_3, Time_4 (400 orders available for each timeslot - location combination)

Incoming Drop off location: Location_1, Location_2 
Incoming Drop off time: Time_1, Time_2, Time_3, Time_4 (400 orders available for each timeslot - location combination)
```

It seems like I should be able to achieve this by creating the following variants, and enable stock limits as follows:

```
Destination_1, Location_1, Time_1 - Stock limit = 400 
Destination_1, Location_1, Time_2 - Stock limit = 400 
Destination_1, Location_2, Time_3 - Stock limit = 400 
Destination_1, Location_2, Time_4 - Stock limit = 400 
Destination_1, Any Location, Any Time - Stock limit = 1000
```

However, it seems to only apply the stock limit of 400, and not the 1000 stock limit. Specifically, it only applies the stock limit of the row that is higher on the list of variations.

Ideally it is all under one 'product' so that we can skip the "Shop" page in the user flow.

Can you advise on the way for me to achieve what I'm looking to do?

Thanks in advance!

Demo:
http://www.sasfestivalservices.com/product/festival-crate